# Whether I can use nuget packages instead of crystal report run time.(Whether this will replace crystal run time installation in client machine)

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2008

I wanted to know whether we will be able to run a windows application (with crystal reports) without installing crystal report run time (I will add the package from  `nuget`, would that be fine?)

I am unable to run the application with out crystal report runtime.